# ASIHttpRequest. Turn off cache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHttpRequest for my iphone applications. How do i turn off cache, so nothing get cache?

I found something that looked good, but I have no idea if its right or not.

```
[request setCachePolicy: ASIDoNotWriteToCacheCachePolicy | ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine.

(see docs here : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#about_cache_policies, in the section 'About cache policies')

Answer (score 0):

It does look right. You can find more about caching and ASIHTTPRequest [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#about_cache_policies)